# Is there a sortable ('order by') alternative to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I'm in the process of looking for a way to find a sortable alternative to a column that is populated with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and I'm stumped at the moment.

I have a web based form with multiple fields including a field that is hidden on the form that writes the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to the database when the form is submitted.

The challenge I'm facing is that I want to create reports from these forms (sorting by month, week, or year) and order them by the timestamp but based on what I've seen [here,](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/44613/how-can-order-by-current-timestamp-successfully-im.html) sorting is not possible.

Is there an alternative I can use to achieve the results I want?

Comment: @PaulWhite or `OVER (ANY_ABRITRARY_ORDER_YOU_LIKE)`

Comment: @PaulWhite - Basically I want to pull all records that were entered into the database (for example) during a given month based on the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Is it a given month or is it the current month?

Comment: @AaronBertrand They're basically month end reports for the management types broken down by Month, YTD, and things like that.

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. Are you always basing the date range on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or are you sometimes expecting to dictate a date range?

Comment: @PaulWhite - I'll edit based on this wealth of information (which I'm still sorting through) as I was unsure what I had to work with when I made my original post.  Stay tuned.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was originally basing the date range on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  As previously posted below, I haven't really been in this scenario before so I'm doing information gathering/learning so I can program the right solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea why you would want to `ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. If the table has a column where you stored `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when the row was created, you just need to say:

```
ORDER BY that_column_name;
```

Or if you want newest first:

```
ORDER BY that_column_name DESC;
```

... in other words, forget *how* the column was populated.

Now, if the comments are accurate, and you're actually not concerned so much about *ordering* but rather about *filtering*, then perhaps what you want is:

```
-- create a DATE variable based on today:

DECLARE @s DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

-- convert it to the first of the month
-- (you can do this in the step above,
-- just separating it for clarity):

SET @s = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(@s), @s);

-- use >= and < in a WHERE clause, and order by that column
-- (however this is just a coincidence, order by and filtering
-- are completely unrelated in this case:

SELECT [?] FROM dbo.[?]
  WHERE [datetime_column] >= @s
  AND [datetime_column] < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @s)
  ORDER BY [datetime_column];
```

Here is why you don't want to use BETWEEN, in case anyone sends you that way:

- https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Here is why you want to use built-in date functions and a native DATE type and not convert to a string to trim time from a datetime variable:

- http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime
- http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time

And here is some general information about bad practices in date/range queries:

- https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries
- https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly
- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/

Comment: When I add complexity to a statement such as  `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE current_timestamp_column >= 'Jan 01 2013 10:00AM' order by current_timestamp_column` I only get partial results.  If I'm going to sort by Month, for example, out of 30 records that would qualify, only 20 show up.

Comment: Well why are you saying `Jan 01 2013 10:00AM` instead of `2013-01-01T10:00`? Why do you think this problem has anything to do with `ORDER BY`?

Comment: I was unaware of this.  Never been in this situation with this scenaro before.  Is there a link that I could look over to learn up on it?

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Comment: More importantly, `ORDER BY` will never change the number of rows returned, it can only change the order.

Comment: Thanks @aaronbertrand for the assistance and education.  I was able to convert all the dates correctly and filter the records out by the correct date.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can do that using datepart function.
create view and add the 3 more column 
as datepart(mm,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) month,
datepart(wk,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) week
datepart(yy,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) year and apply the sort operation on view.

for more information you can refer to [Datepart Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp)

Comment: So confused. How is creating three contrived columns and ordering by them individually better than ordering by the column itself? Also if you really mean `ORDER BY CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` then what does the order by mean, really? Isn't it the same value on every row?

Comment: hi as per your question you want to sort by month, week, year

Comment: no I think you've missed several important things here...